# Linq query to calculate sum of object properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Customers `List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();`with this format

```
class Customer {
    public string Name;
    public string City;
    public Order[] Orders;

}

class Order {
    public int Quantity;
    public Product Product;

}

class Product {
    public string Name;
    public decimal Price;
}
```

Every customer is instantiated like this:

```
    Customer customer3 = new Customer {
        Name = "Kostas",
        City = "Athens",
        Orders = new Order[] {
            new Order {Quantity = 1, Product = new Product {Name = "Juice", Price = 20 } },
        },
    };
```

I want to write a LINQ query that prints out the name of the customer and the total amount of all the orders.

So far after lots of tries the closest i have done is this, but it does not work as intended.

```
        var query= from c in customers
                        from p in c.Orders
                        let summary = p.Product.Price * p.Quantity
                        select new {c.Name, summary };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select` to create a list of anonymous objects with the `Sum` of the order quantity and product price. Note that this is using expression syntax rather than query syntax.

```
var query = customers.Select(c => new {
    Name = c.Name,
    OrderTotal = c.Orders.Sum(o => o.Quantity * o.Product.Price)
});
```

This will result in an `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` is an anonymous object containing props for the `Name` and `OrderTotal`.

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm. Could you please write the SQL- like version as well, for educational purposes

Comment: @John that's out of scope of this question, and in order to avoid cluttering up this answer it's probably best if you ask another question for that. Make sure to show your relevant database schema. I will say you're going to need to use `inner join`, `group by` and `sum` though.

Answer (score 0):

you should be change your way to solve it.

I think you should be create a property for 'summary' on customer class

like this

```
  class Customer
{
    public string Name;
    public string City;
    public Order[] Orders;
    public int Summary
    {
        get
        {
            int result = 0;
            foreach(Order order in this.Orders)
            {
                result += order.Product * order.Quantity;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can get just foreach code, simply

```
        foreach(Customer customer in customers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", customer.Name, customer.Summary);
        }
```